# Sprintf of MAC address of available networks

Tags: c, printf, mac-address

I want to sprintf Mac address of some found networks in this area like this:

```
      `WiFi connection settings:
      MAC: 00 1E C0 10 3B 19
       SSID:         css`
```

my code is :

```
char buf[32];
BYTE MAC[64];
int i;

for(i=1;i<15;i++)
{   
    MyScanResults = WFScanList(i);
    sprintf(buf,"%s", MyScanResults.ssid);
    sprintf(&MAC[i*2],"%02x", MyScanResults.bssid[i]);
    _dbgwrite("SSID:         ");
    _dbgwrite(buf);
    _dbgwrite("\n");
    _dbgwrite("MAC:         ");
    _dbgwrite(MAC);
}
```

and Errors are :

> C:\Users\h\Desktop\WiFi test\taskFlyport.c:22: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'sprintf' differ in signedness <
>
> C:\Users\h\Desktop\WiFi test\taskFlyport.c:27: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of '_dbgwrite' differ in signedness<

is there anyone to tell me where is my problem?
thanks,regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BYTE is an `unsigned char` and `MAC` is thus an `unsigned char[]`.

`sprintf` wants `char*`.

Change MAC's declaration to:

```
char MAC[64];
```

Here's a demo:

```
char mac[64];
unsigned long long testMac = 0xAABBCCDDEEFF;

// without spaces
sprintf(mac, "MAC is: %llX", testMac);
printf("%s\n", mac);

// with spaces - not sure if order is correct!
unsigned char* pTestMac = (unsigned char*)&testMac;
sprintf(mac, "MAC is: %X %X %X %X %X %X",
    (unsigned)pTestMac[5],
    (unsigned)pTestMac[4],
    (unsigned)pTestMac[3],
    (unsigned)pTestMac[2],
    (unsigned)pTestMac[1],
    (unsigned)pTestMac[0]
    );
printf("%s\n", mac);
```

Output:

```
MAC is: AABBCCDDEEFF
MAC is: AA BB CC DD EE FF
```

Comment: thank you for reply .I wrote byte according to related structure definition, Now I don't have any warning but my results is the same and like :MAC:??5217356f, and MAC: ??5217

Comment: @HOsseiNSA This is because your loop starts with `i = 1`, causing you to skip the two first characters in `MAC`.

Comment: @HOsseiNSA - added code. Note that the printf format you used wasn't meant for large numbers (64bit). See my demo code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like what is done in some projects as [wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/):

They define some macros to help printing MAC adresses ([link](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob;f=src/utils/common.h;h=028a5eff729e951d14d98c8688dea312b99c2d85;hb=HEAD#l420)):

```
#define MAC2STR(a) (a)[0], (a)[1], (a)[2], (a)[3], (a)[4], (a)[5]
#define MACSTR "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x"
```

And finally use it like that ([link](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob;f=wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.c;h=e8bca8a8a1f4c4bb045f203b0f72082d3c28b476;hb=HEAD#l191)):

```
unsigned char mac[6] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66};
printf("My mac is " MACSTR "\n", MAC2STR(mac));
```

The output is:

```
My mac is 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

Which is much easier to use in a whole project.